# jQuery each looping once

Tags: jquery, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var country = ["United States", "Canada", "Australia", "United Kingdom"];
        var state = {
            "United States": "Alaska",
            "United States" : "Alabama"
        };
        $(this).click(function () {
            if ($.inArray($(this).val(), country)) {
                $.each(state, function (key, val) {
                    if ($("#country").val() == key) {
                        $("#state").append("<option value=" + val + ">" + val + "</option>");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is, I have a Multi-select for the Countries, I want to populate "#state" based on what a user clicks on for Countries, right now it's only showing the first item "Alaska" under the multiple select.

Not exactly sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Create a JS fiddle or stack snippet

Comment: `$(this).click(function(){` clicking what? `document` in your case.

Comment: Your `state` contains different values for the key "United States".

Comment: Please for the love of god don't use state for UK

Comment: State is just a variable I use to hold the territories of different countries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do:

```
var state = {
    "United States" : "Alaska",
    "United States" : "Alabama"
};
```

Keys in an object must be unique. Your second `"United States"` key overwrites the first `"United States"` key, leaving your object being *just*:

```
var state = {
    "United States" : "Alabama"
};
```

Instead, you'll need to store an object, which maps countries to states:

```
var state = {
    "United States" : ["Alaska", "Alabama"],
    "United Kingdom" : ["Scotland", "England"] // "states" in the UK?
};
```

... and then alter your click handler accordingly:

```
$(this).click(function () {
    if ($.inArray($(this).val(), country)) {
        $.each(state, function (key, val) {
            if ($("#country").val() == key) {
                $.each(val, function (i, name) { 
                    $("#state").append("<option value=" + name + ">" + name + "</option>");
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Note**:

1. Your `$(this).click()` selector is likely wrong. It should likely be an ID or class selector (e.g. `$('#your_id')`, `$('.your-class')`).
2. You'll probably want to *empty* the `$('#state')` select before you append to it. To do this, add `$(this).children().remove()` within the click handler (but outside of the loops).
3. I'm not sure why you're keeping an array of country names, as well as a object mapping country names to states; do-away with `country`, and just use the keys of `state` to get your countries.
4. Remember that `$().val()` for a multi-select returns an array of the results, not a single value.

With all of these notes taken into account, and with some misc. tidying, here's the code I've come up with:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var countries = {
        "United States": ["Alaska", "Alabama"],
        "United Kingdom": ["Scotland", "England"] // "states" in the UK?
    };

    // SETUP: Ignore this bit.
    Object.keys(countries).forEach(function (val) {
       $('#multiselect').append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>');
    });
    // END SETUP.

    $('#multiselect').change(function () {
        var vals = $(this).val();
        var states = $('#state');
        
        states.children().remove();
        
        jQuery.each(vals, function (i, name) {          
            var country = countries[name];
            
            jQuery.each(country, function (i, val) {
                states.append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>');
            });
        });
    });    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" id="multiselect"></select>
<select multiple="multiple" id="state"></select>
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/6dnbgf24/1/

Comment: Nice **note**, and actually a complete answer.

Comment: Think you can help with this? I'm using this in a multiselect, and when I select more than one "country" it only outputs states for the first one I selected.

Comment: @AnthonyVasquez: can you come up with a sample on jsFiddle, which shows the JavaScript and HTML you're using? In particular, I'm not sure what `#country` and `#state` are/ do. I've come up with http://jsfiddle.net/6dnbgf24/, not sure if that helps you.

Comment: Hi Matt, the #states is also a Multiselect.

Comment: @AnthonyVasquez: That won't make a difference. The code I just posted will still work, simply by adding the `multiple` attribute to the `#state` element; http://jsfiddle.net/6dnbgf24/1/

Comment: One last request, when selecting two countries it repeats the certain states under #states.

Comment: @AnthonyVasquez: Can you post an updated jsFiddle showing that? I can't replicate it on http://jsfiddle.net/6dnbgf24/1/.

Comment: @AnthonyVasquez: 1) you'll need to uncomment `states.children().remove();` otherwise each time you re-select some new countries, the states will get appended to `#state`, without clearing the ones that were previously there 2) as I said before `$().val()` returns an array when called on a multi-select list, which is why you see the country names repeated in the header you're generating for each country in `#state` to fix that, use `val` instead of `$('#country').val()` there. Once you've made those changes, it seems to work; http://jsfiddle.net/tfcvm2uc/1/

Comment: @Matt, I would like to be able to select more than one country if I wished without having any data repeating, not sure if thats possible.

Comment: @AnthonyVasquez: You usually do that by holding down CTRL on your keyboard, whilst choosing from the multi-select; that lets you select multiple elements. Otherwise, how can you differentiate between a user wanting to select another option (with the previous selection), and wanting to start a new selection?

Comment: @Matt, I feel stupid it, I wasn't holding down CTRL. Sorry! Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @AnthonyVasquez: Hehe, treat it as something new you've learnt today :).

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to set multiple values with the same key, you have to wrap the values into an array this way:

```
var state = {
"United States" : ["Alaska", "Alabama"]
};
```

And then update your code accordingly:

```
$.each(state, function(key, val){           
    for( var i in val){
        $("#state").append("<option value="+val[i]+">"+val[i]+"</option>");
        }
    });
```

The above code has not been tested, may contain unmatched parenthesis.

Comment: Worked like a charm, you saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myJson = {
    "country": [
        {
            "name": "United States",
            "id": "usa",
            "states": [
                {
                    "name": "State 1 USA",
                    "id": "usaState1",
                    "cid": "usa",
                    "cities": [
                        {
                            "name": "City 1",
                            "id": "usaState1City1",
                            "area": "12345 sqkm"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "City 2",
                            "id": "usaState1City2",
                            "area": "12345 sqkm"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "State 2 USA",
                    "id": "usaState2",
                    "cid": "usa",
                    "cities": [
                        {
                            "name": "City 3",
                            "id": "usaState2City3",
                            "area": "12345 sqkm"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "City 4",
                            "id": "usaState2City4",
                            "area": "12345 sqkm"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Australia",
            "id": "aus",
            "states": [
                {
                    "name": "State 1 Australia",
                    "id": "ausState1",
                    "cid": "aus",
                    "cities": [
                        {
                            "name": "City 5",
                            "id": "ausState1City5",
                            "area": "12345 sqkm"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "City 6",
                            "id": "ausState1City6",
                            "area": "12345 sqkm"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "State 2 Australia",
                    "id": "ausState2",
                    "cid": "aus",
                    "cities": [
                        {
                            "name": "City 7",
                            "id": "ausState2City7",
                            "area": "12345 sqkm"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "City 8",
                            "id": "ausState2City8",
                            "area": "12345 sqkm"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}


$(document).ready(function(){
$.each(myJson.country, function (index, value) {
    //alert(value.name);
    $("#country").append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
});

$("#country").click(function () { 
      var countryId = $(this).val();

        if(cntryId !=''){
           $('#selectedvalue').val($(this).val());
        }else{
           $('#selectedvalue').val($(this).val());
        }
      var cntryId   =$('#selectedvalue').val();
      var exist     = cntryId.indexOf(','); 
      if(parseInt(exist) > 0){
           $("#state").html('');
          var array     = cntryId.split(",");
          $.each(array,function(i){  
                selectedId =array[i];               
                getState(selectedId);   
            });
        }else{
            $("#state").html('');
            getState(cntryId)
        }   

});

});

function getState(countryId){
     $.each(myJson.country, function (index, value) {
                    var state =value.states;

                    $.each(state, function (indexState, valueState) {
                            //alert(countryId+"=="+valueState.cid);
                            if(countryId==valueState.cid){
                                $("#state").append('<option value="'+value.indexState+'">'+valueState.name+'</option>');
                            }
                    });
    });

}

</script>

<form id="dropdowns" action="index.html">

            <label>Country:</label>
                <select id="country" name="country" multiple>
                    <option value="000">-Select Country-</option>
                </select>

            <br />

            <label>State:</label>
                <select id="state" name="network">
                    <option value="000">-Select State-</option>
                </select>

            <br />

            <label>City:</label>
                <select id="model" name="model">
                    <option value="000">-Select City-</option>
                </select>

            <br />
                <input type="hidden" id="selectedvalue" value="">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm looking for a multiselect, not a drop down list.